# How to redirect jsp page after session expired?

Tags: java, jsp, session

```
<%
   if(session == null) {
       System.out.println("Expire");
       response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
    }else{
       System.out.println("Not Expire");
    }
 %>

 <%
   HttpSession sess = request.getSession(false);
   String email = sess.getAttribute("email").toString();
   Connection conn = Database.getConnection();
   Statement st = conn.createStatement();
   String sql = "select * from login where email = '" + email + "' ";
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
 %>
```

I tried to redirect the login.jsp page when session is expired.
But I am geeting error in "String email = sesss.getAttribute("email").toString();".

So anyone please help me to solve this error.

Basically I want to redirect to login.jsp page when the session is expired.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You need to either 1) place the whole lot in the `if` or 2) `return`. Or 3) never, ever, use scriptlets ever again - they've been very bad practice for a decade now; no one should be using them.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm with you at no. 3, especially the database connection thing makes me shudder.

Comment: I changed some code.
if(session.getAttribute("email") == null) {
 System.out.println("Expire");
 response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}else{
 System.out.println("Not Expire");
}

I will get the "Expire" text but still didnt redirect to "login.jsp" page.
And facing same error of second lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and its working fine for me.

```
<%
    if(session.getAttribute("email") == null) {
       response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
       return ;
    }
%>
```

I just put return statement and It will redirect to "login.jsp" when the session is expired.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You are mixing JSP and Java code. You should separate it.
Keep Java code in controllers.

You can use:

```
if(request.getSession(false) == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
}
```

"...If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method returns null."

Answer (score 0):

For example create Authentication Filter

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "AuthenticationFilter",
    description = "Authentication Filter",
    urlPatterns = "/AuthenticationFilter"
```

)
@WebFilter("*.jsp")
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

```
private ServletContext context;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.context = filterConfig.getServletContext();
    this.context.log("AuthenticationFilter initialized");
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    //close any resources here
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    String uri = req.getRequestURI();
    this.context.log("Requested Resource::" + uri);

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
    Object user_o = req.getSession().getAttribute("username");
    this.context.log("Authentication Filter, user_name::" + user_o);

    if (user_o == null && !(uri.endsWith("index.jsp") || uri.endsWith("LoginUser"))) {
        this.context.log("None authenticatied request, session:: " + session);
        res.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

    } else {
        this.context.log("Authenticatied request, session:: " + session);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```